# How to update Cloudant document using Objective-C

Tags: cloudant

I have a document in a Cloudant database. How do I modify the document using Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudant is based on CouchDB and one of the core ideas of CouchDB is that all the requests are HTTP-based. So you can access coudant same way as you do usual HTTP requests.

Comment: Something like AFNetworking can simplify the HTTP side of things, I've used it with success.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a CouchDB client Objective-C library:

- [Unit tests](https://github.com/Hypertopic/lib-objc/blob/master/hypertopic-framework/Test/TestHTDatabase.m)
- [Implementation](https://github.com/Hypertopic/lib-objc/blob/master/hypertopic-framework/Classes/HTDatabase.m#L129)

Answer (score 0):

Use the link https://github.com/gunjankumr/CouchDBDemo to get a complete project to create, insert, delete and update a CloudAnt document.

Answer (score 0):

You can either roll your own HTTP requests using NSURLSession, or there are a number of libraries available to do this, cloudant have an official Objective-C library in [ObjectoveCloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/objective-cloudant) which can be installed via CocoaPods.